# jQueryからOnsenUIの画面遷移を実行出来ますか？

Tags: jquery, onsen-ui

初めて質問させて頂きます。何卒よろしくお願い致します。

質問内容はOnsenUIとjQueryをつかったハイブリッドアプリ実装に関する事で、jQuery側で動的に作成したli要素のOnでクリックイベントをハンドルした際に、OnsenUI側のons.navigatorに対してpushPageを発動させる為にはどのようにすれば宜しいでしょうか？

ページ構成としてはOnsenUIのスライディングメニューを使っておりますので、index.html内で下記のようにons-sliding-menuタグを記述し、

```
<ons-sliding-menu var="app.slidingMenu" menu-page="menu.html" main-page="home.html" side="left" type="overlay" max-slide-distance="200px">
```

さらに同ページ内で各メニュー選択時にセットアップされるmain-pageごとにons.readyで必要処理を記述しております。

下記はスライディングメニュー選択時にセットされるページの1つで、Ajax通信で取得したデータを表示するためにjQueryで動的生成したli要素に対して、クリックイベントの中からOnsenUIのpushPageを実行して画面遷移しようとしています。

```
module.controller('ctrl_search.html', function($scope) {
  ons.ready(function() {
    $(".cs-ulh").on('click', 'li', function(){
      myNavigator.pushPage('g_search_detail.html');
    });
  });
});
```

上記のように対象となるに対し、単純にpushPageと記述しても動作しません。

これを実現させる為にはどのようにすべきなのでしょうか？

### ※もう少し具体的な情報を追記させて頂きます。

■index.html

```
<ons-sliding-menu var="app.slidingMenu" menu-page="menu.html" main-page="home.html" side="left" type="overlay" max-slide-distance="200px">
</ons-sliding-menu>

module.controller('ctrl_search.html', function($scope) {
  ons.ready(function() {

    // AJAX通信後に動的にli要素生成
    function ajaxRequest(reqPrm){
      var errcount = 0;
      $.ajax({
        },success: function(json){
          for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
            $(".cs-ulh").append(li要素を追加);
          }
      });
    }

    // 動的生成されたliクリックでsearch.detail.htmlに遷移
    $(".cs-ulh").on('click', 'li', function(){
      myNavigator.pushPage('g_search_detail.html');
    });

  });
});
```

---

■home.html

```
<ons-navigator var="myNavigator">
  <ons-page ng-controller="ctrl_home.html">
    <ons-toolbar></ons-toolbar>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

---

■search.html

```
<ons-page ng-controller="ctrl_search.html">
  <ons-toolbar>...</ons-toolbar>
  <ul class="cs-ulh"></ul>
</ons-page>
```

---

当該関連個所だけ抜き出すとこんな感じです。
index.htmlで記述されているスライディングメニューでは、
main-pageとしてhome.htmlを指定。
home.htmlの中で、ons-navigatorのvar=myNavigatorを設定。
search.htmlの中でul要素にclass指定しています。
そしてindex.htmlの中ではAjax通信の後にli要素を動的生成して、
その動的li要素がクリックされたときにpushPageを実行しています。
これでも動作しないのですが何が問題なのでしょうか？
何卒ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

部分的ではなく全体を見ないとどこが問題か判断できませんが、

AngularJSのコントローラー定義

```
ng-controller="ctrl_search.html"
```

クラス定義(HTML)

```
class="cs-ulh"
```

Onsen UIのナビゲーター定義

```
<ons-navigator var="myNavigator">
```

遷移先のhtmlファイル

```
g_search_detail.html
```

これらが適切に設定されていれば動作はすると思います。

Monaca IDEであればブラウザのコンソール等、開発環境で何かエラーは出ていませんか？

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます、本文に詳しい内容を追記させて頂きましたのでご教授頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: @OnsenUI初心者 search.htmlが唐突に出てきましたが、home.htmlとsearch.htmlは同時に表示されているのでしょうか？
home.htmlではなくsearch.htmlにons-navigatorを定義するのはダメですか？

Comment: はい、それで解決致しました。最初に設定されるhome.htmlにさえons-navigatorがあれば、メニューの他ページへの画面遷移はpushPageの動作と同様で、home.html以外のページにはons-navigatorが不要なのかと認識違いしておりました。適切なアドバイスを心より感謝致します。